# How to convert logic of a bar chart into a line chart visualization

Tags: html, d3.js

I have this query that builds a basic bar chart visualization based on 20 random numbers I generate.

Is there a way to simply do this and convert to a line without totally uprooting the integrity of what I have?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>

            var w = 500;
            var h = 200;

            var dataset = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                var newNum = Math.random() * 25;
                dataset.push(newNum)
            };

            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width",w)
                        .attr("height",h);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (barWidth + barPadding);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - (d * 6);
               })
               .attr("width", barWidth)
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return d * 6;
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d * 10) + ")";
               });

               svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return Math.round(d);
                })
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (barWidth + barPadding) + barWidth / 2;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - (d * 6) + 15;
                })
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "11px")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("fill", "white");
                
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to find a way to convert this into a line graph without a scaleLinear d3 function. I've tried multiple routes - including changing the rectangles into dots and connecting the circles, but it's really just got to be a straight line across each data point.